# Datagridview does not show data

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have created a simple table inside  Nortwind db.I am trying to retrieve all data using datagridview .I think missed out something because nothing displays in datagridview.There is no exception and error massages just doesnt work

```
public void getData() 
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cnn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from info",con);
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adp.Fill(ds);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
}
```

Comment: does `ds` contain anything?

Comment: con.Open() is missing

Comment: @dumass The DataAdapter will open and close the connection itself.

Comment: just a tought : You shoudl wrap your `SqlConnection` and your `SqlDataAdapter` in using block. You should also (IMHO) add a try/catch block around your statement

Comment: I suspect you need to call `dataGridView1.DataBind()`

Comment: how about command type?

Comment: Please post your connection string

Comment: @LarsTech - thank you for the info.I didn't know it.I deleted my answer as its misleading..

Comment: Thank you i found a solution    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

Answer (score 3):

Use a `DataTable` instead of a `DataSet`

Otherwise, you need to specify which table the `DataGridView` should show.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify which table the DataGridView should show.
Try following code snippet.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```